# Using definite integrals with velocity and acceleration

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, physics

Rocket A is traveling 49 ft/sec at 80 seconds. Rocket B is launched upward with an acceleration of $$a(t)=\frac3{\sqrt{t +1}}$$. At time t=0 seconds, the initial height of the rocket is 0 feet, and the initial velocity is 2 feet per second. Which of the two rockets is traveling faster at t=80 seconds?

Comment: What is acceleration compared to velocity ?

Comment: Acceleration is the derivative of velocity

Comment: OK. So, velocity is the ??? of acceleration, isn't ?

Comment: yes I understand the relationship between acceleration and velocity however I don't understand how to use the information given to solve using the relationship.

Comment: So, velocity is the antiderivative of acceleration. Is this way of explaining making things clearer ? We have the same with velocity and distance. Let us continue until you are sure. Getting the answer is not important; understanding is !

Comment: Yes that I understand

Answer (score 1):

$a(t) = \frac{dv}{dt}$ where v(t) is the velocity.
Then $v(t) = \int{a(t)dt}$. Use the condition for velocity at $t = 0$ to obtain the integration constant. Then you can get velocity at $t = 80$.

Comment: How do you set up the finding the integration constant?

Comment: You do the integral shown.  You will come out with $v(t)=something+C$, where $something$ is the result of the integral.  Now substitute in $t=0, v(0)=2$ and you will get an equation in $C$

Comment: So if i did it correctly i believe i should get c=0?

Comment: $c$ can be anything based on the condition. Why do you think you should get $c = 0$?

Comment: I plugged in 2 for v(t) and 1 in for the t of my integrated equation and solved for c. So it looked like 2=2(0+1)^3/2 +c. I solved for c=0

Comment: Check your integration procedure. What's $\int{x^{-1/2}dx}$?

Comment: Ah shoot I forgot the negative. v(t)= 6(t+1)^1/2 +c. Therefore C should equal -4